# Transpose rows to columns in SQL with categorical values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to transpose categorical values from rows to columns in SQL

Example

```
create table sample1 (
    Col1 nvarchar(max),
    [Values] nvarchar(max),
)

insert into sample1
values ('CatA','XCY'), ('CatB','XCY'), ('CatA','XC'), ('CatB','XC'), ('CatA','KJ'), ('CatA','KG'),('CatA','KFD'), ('CatB','KG')
```

`select * from sample1` (will give you below values)

```
Col1    Values
CatA    XCY
CatB    XCY
CatA    XC
CatB    XC
CatA    KJ
CatA    KG
CatA    KFD
CatB    KG
```

expected output

```
CatA   CatB
XCY    XCY
XC     XC
KJ     NULL
KG     KG
KFD    NULL
```

I tried with below approach but not getting

```
select *
from
(
  select [Values], Col1
  from sample1
) d
pivot
(
  max([Values])
  for Col1 in (CatA, CatB)
) piv;
```

Comment: Your question implies that there exist some group which contains one value from category A and one from category B.  But your table is lacking any column(s) which provide this ordering.

Comment: @DaleK PIVOT won't help much here until the OP includes the missing data.

Comment: @Rakshu, you need to number the rows if you want a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by a full join, which makes sure both sides can get their values and fills out missing ones with NULLs:

```sql
create table sample1 (
Col1 nvarchar(max),
[Values] nvarchar(max),
)

insert into sample1
values ('CatA','XCY'), ('CatB','XCY'), ('CatA','XC'), ('CatB','XC'), ('CatA','KJ'), ('CatA','KG'),('CatA','KFD'), ('CatB','KG')

select a.[values] as catA, b.[values] as catB
from (
    select col1, [values]
    from sample1
    where col1 = 'CatA'
    ) a
full join (
    select col1, [values]
    from sample1
    where col1 = 'CatB'
    ) b
    ON b.[values] = a.[values]
```

Output:

| catA | catB |
| --- | --- |
| XCY | XCY |
| XC | XC |
| KJ | NULL |
| KG | KG |
| KFD | NULL |

Answer (score 3):

One option, using the conditional aggregation as follows :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'CatA' THEN [Values] END) AS CatA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'CatB' THEN [Values] END) AS CatB
FROM sample1
GROUP BY [Values]
ORDER BY [Values] DESC
```

Results :

```
CatA    CatB
XCY     XCY
XC      XC
KJ      null
KG      KG
KFD     null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/i8DiFrAf)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `PIVOT`, you need to number the rows appropriately with `DENSE_RANK()` in a separate column:

```
SELECT [CatA], [CatB]
FROM (  
   SELECT Col1, [Values], DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Values] DESC) AS Rn
   FROM sample1
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX([Values]) FOR Col1 IN ([CatA], [CatB])
) p
```

With this approach (or with conditional aggregation) you can easily include additional categories:

```
SELECT [CatA], [CatB], [CatC], ...
FROM ( ... ) t
PIVOT (MAX([Values]) FOR Col1 IN ([CatA], [CatB], [CatC], ...)) p
```

Another option is `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
; WITH A AS (
   select [Values] AS CatA
   from sample1 
   WHERE Col1 = 'CatA'
), B AS (
   select [Values] AS CatB
   from sample1 
   WHERE Col1 = 'CatB'
)  
SELECT *
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.CatA = B.CatB
```

Result:

| CatA | CatB |
| --- | --- |
| XCY | XCY |
| XC | XC |
| KJ | *null* |
| KG | KG |
| KFD | *null* |

Answer (score 0):

looking at your data, you could use a query like below:

```
create table sample1 (
    Col1 nvarchar(max),
    [Values] nvarchar(max),
)

insert into sample1
values ('CatA','XCY'), ('CatB','XCY'), ('CatA','XC'), ('CatB','XC'), ('CatA','KJ'), ('CatA','KG'),('CatA','KFD'), ('CatB','KG')

Select A.Values As CatA, B.Values as CatB from
(select distinct Values from sample1 where Col1='CatA' )A
full join
(select distinct Values from sample1 where Col1='CatB') B
 on A.Values=B.Values
```

See demo here on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sv0RVj3v)